# work flow for using git 2.5 for multiple work directories using 'git worktree'

Tags: git, github, linux-mint

Being very new to git, I'm trying to get an overview of how to use multiple work directories for different branches off one github project.
In particular I want/need to work on two branches - one the 'master' the other one a maintenance release, say maintenance/project1.
The plan is to run the work under Linux/Mint 17.2.
As well, I would like to make use of the latest git worktree features  introduced in 2.5.

Assuming I have a github account, have forked my own fork off the main project and have cloned the fork to my local machine in ~/user/myproject.

As things stand now, I don't expect to contribute code via git push, all the results of my work & testing will be passed on to others for possible fixes via e-mail - doing it via git might be nice down the road, but won't be necessary to start.

What I see as the steps I would need a corresponding set of git commands for are:

- Creating the two work tree
- Switching between these trees
- Keeping both trees up-to-date with the upstream master
- any other cautions/ special considerations for working this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Creating the two work trees

1. git clone https://github.com/someone/someproject.git

   (this will give you directory `someproject` on the `master` branch)
2. `cd someproject; git worktree add ../someproject-devel devel`

   (this will give you directory `someproject-devel` on the `devel` branch, assuming such a branch exists)

> Switching between these trees

Just use the `cd` command.

> Keeping both trees up-to-date with the upstream master

Just `cd` in the appropriate directory and run `git pull`. Doing this in the main working tree first may be best, but is not required (the man page does not address this specifically, and I haven't looked into the worktree implementation in detail.  If an issue existed it would only be one of optimal use of space, not functionality).

> any other cautions/ special considerations for working this way.

From the man page:

```
   Multiple checkout in general is still experimental, and the support for
   submodules is incomplete. It is NOT recommended to make multiple
   checkouts of a superproject.
```

Comment: Do I need to add any remotes for each directory or just one for the main clone directory?

Comment: Your worktrees share remotes with your main repository.  Any changes you make to remotes in the main repository will be visible in all worktrees.

Comment: How can I recover if I fetch or pull the wrong upstream data in the wrong directory? :-(

Comment: How would you do that? If you're only ever typing `git pull`, you're never going to accidentally pull the wrong thing.  And if you do, I guess that's what `git reset` and your reflog are for.

Comment: I am still a bit confused, I think.
To be safe, I restarted, but after I create my 'devel' branch and rub 'git status' in the main directory, it tells me:

Comment: user@Leno ~/gramps $ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 mygramps42/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
user@Leno ~/gramps $ 

Where mygramps is my 'devel' branch.
should I not be trying to get the updates from 'upstream'??
Something is not right here.

Comment: yeah I think this part "assuming such a branch exists" is confusing. So you have to set up the new branch the way you would normally, before you can use any of this?