# How to create a separate branch in a separate directory for a GIT repository

Tags: git, version-control, branch, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a web server where I host a live site which is connected to the master branch through `bitbucket` using Source Tree. When I make changes on my local computer, I commit the changes and then pull them on the live server.

I want to setup a staging site next to the live site so that:

1. I can develop locally on the staging branch, committing it and then pull it onto the server into the staging site.
2. When I'm happy with the results from testing the staging site, I would merge staging into the master branch (the live site).

I'm not sure how to go about this. I am relatively new to `GIT`. I've created a new branch in SourceTree however I can't see how you specify what folder that branch runs off etc.

Is this the right way of going about things or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

A given repository can have only one active "working copy" checked out.

If you want to put a branch of the repository into a separate directory, you can clone the directory to there and then switch to the branch.

(You could also just copy the complete directory with your repository, but the clone command does some nice hardlink magic to reduce disk space, which may be a concern if you have a large repository).

Comment: I've done that and they are now coming up as separate repositories in the list. If I make changes to my staging branch, I can then commit them etc as expected. Do I then simply do a merge of the master/staging branch to push changes into the master branch (instead of what I currently do which is commit directly to master from my local PC and do a `git pull`)

Answer (score 0):

Git 2.5 [added experimental support for multiple work trees](https://github.com/blog/2042-git-2-5-including-multiple-worktrees-and-triangular-workflows):

> The new Git subcommand `git worktree` creates additional working trees connected to an existing Git repository [1]. Each *linked working tree* is a pseudo-repository with its own checked-out working copy. Its `.git` is actually a file that refers to the history and references from the main repository.
>
> Please note that the worktree feature is experimental. It may have some bugs, and its interface may change based on user feedback. It's **not recommended** to use `git worktree` with a repository that contains submodules.

If your version of Git is new enough you can do something like `git subtree add /path/to/staging/directory staging-branch`.

See also [work flow for using git 2.5 for multiple work directories using 'git worktree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193360/work-flow-for-using-git-2-5-for-multiple-work-directories-using-git-worktree)